# Query database Base on Tag

Tags: php, mysql, database

My table is like this

```
 _________________________________
| product_id   | tag_name         |
|--------------|------------------|
|      1       |  tag1,tag2,tag3  |
|      2       |  tag2,tag4,tag6  |
|      3       |  tag1,tag3       |
|      4       |  tag4,tag2,tag1  | 
 ---------------------------------
```

i want to show the products contains `tag3`. How to query database in php?

Thanks in advance.

I have changed table design to this.

```
     __________________________
    | tag_id       | tag_name  |
    |--------------|-----------|
    |      1       |  tag1     |
    |      2       |  tag2     |
    |      3       |  tag3     |
    |      4       |  tag4     | 
     --------------------------

     __________________________
    | product_id   |  tag_id   |
    |--------------|-----------|
    |      1       |     1     |
    |      2       |     1     |
    |      3       |     2     |
    |      4       |     3     |
    |      5       |     4     |
    |      6       |     3     | 
     --------------------------
```

I think this one is better than first one. Is it?

Comment: This is a great example of why you should not store multiple values in one column. Normalize your data now, before life gets harder still.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set)

```
select * from your_table
where find_in_set('tag3', tag_name) > 0
```

#### But actually you should consider changing your table design. Never store multiple values in one column!

Comment: Thanx. I think better is creating two tables one with tag name and tagID another for creating relation between productID and tagID. Is it what u mean? @juergen

Comment: Exactly. That would be best.

Answer (score 1):

A simple but very vague solution is:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE tag_name LIKE '%tag3%'
```

However, your table design is wrong, you should have another table like this:
product_id tag_name
1          tag1
1          tag2
2          tag1

Comment: Too vague to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) which is more strict than the one @amik used.

```
SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('tag3', tag_name)
```